# Deployment jbpm-console.war from Eclipse: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jbpm

I can successfully start both the JBoss Server and the KIE workbench using "ant start.demo," but I would like to configure Eclipse so that I can start the JBoss Server and the KIE workbench within Eclipse. I downloaded the JBoss through the MarketPlace in Eclipse, and created a new JBoss server. The Home Directory of the server in Eclipse is the wildfly-8.1.0.Final folder within the jbpm-installer folder.

When I start the JBoss server in Eclipse, I get the following error describing that the jbpm-console.war file is unable to start (failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war" caused by org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found. Does anyone know how to correctly configure Eclipse so that both the JBoss Server and KIE workbench (jbpm-console) can be started within Eclipse?

```
11:28:48,623 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:668) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:278)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageDrivenBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:244)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processBeanMetaData(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentDescriptor(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

```
11:28:48,627 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-console.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"jbpm-console.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
11:28:48,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name : "jbpm-console.war")
11:28:48,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"

11:28:53,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war (runtime-name: jbpm-console.war) in 4994ms
11:28:53,877 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:28:53,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:28:53,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started in 52549ms - Started 203 of 245 services (87 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:28:54,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name: "jbpm-console.war")
11:28:54,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the standalone-full profile when starting the server manually.  Take a look here to see all the command line parameters we use when starting the server through the installer, you probably want to copy these:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-installer/build.xml#L487

Comment: You're right on that as well. I also had to switch from "standalone.xml" to "standalone-full.xml" in the Eclipse WildFly configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the WildFly configuration in Eclipse, I have to add `-Dorg.kie.demo=false` and `-Dorg.kie.example=false` so that when JBoss server starts, the code doesn't try to pull the example jbpm files from GitHub. Additionally, I had to switch from "standalone.xml" to "standalone-full.xml" also in the Eclipse configuration for the WildFly server.